# asp.net mongo db 'System.TimeoutException: A timeout occurred after 30000ms' in docker compose

Tags: asp.net, mongodb, docker, docker-compose, microservices

I'm getting this error in my asp.API docker-compose logs

```
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware[1]
  An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
  System.TimeoutException: A timeout occurred after 30000ms selecting a server using CompositeServerSelector{ Selectors = MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient+AreSessionsSupportedServerSelector, LatencyLimitingServerSelector{ AllowedLatencyRange = 00:00:00.0150000 }, OperationsCountServerSelector }. Client view of cluster state is { ClusterId : "1", Type : "Unknown", State : "Disconnected", Servers : [{ ServerId: "{ ClusterId : 1, EndPoint : "Unspecified/catalogcommentdb:27015" }", EndPoint: "Unspecified/catalogcommentdb:27015", ReasonChanged: "Heartbeat", State: "Disconnected", ServerVersion: , TopologyVersion: , Type: "Unknown", HeartbeatException: "MongoDB.Driver.MongoConnectionException: An exception occurred while opening a connection to the server.
   ---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (111): Connection refused 172.24.0.4:27015
     at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
     at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
     at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.Connect(Socket socket, EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.TcpStreamFactory.CreateStream(EndPoint endPoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelper(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
     at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.OpenHelper(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Connections.BinaryConnection.Open(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.InitializeConnection(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Servers.ServerMonitor.Heartbeat(CancellationToken cancellationToken)", LastHeartbeatTimestamp: "2022-08-08T12:28:13.2001516Z", LastUpdateTimestamp: "2022-08-08T12:28:13.2001518Z" }] }.
     at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.ThrowTimeoutException(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description)
     at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChangedHelper.HandleCompletedTask(Task completedTask)
     at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.WaitForDescriptionChanged(IServerSelector selector, ClusterDescription description, Task descriptionChangedTask, TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at MongoDB.Driver.Core.Clusters.Cluster.SelectServer(IServerSelector selector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.AreSessionsSupportedAfterServerSelection(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.AreSessionsSupported(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient.StartImplicitSession(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at MongoDB.Driver.OperationExecutor.StartImplicitSession(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.UsingImplicitSession[TResult](Func`2 func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at MongoDB.Driver.MongoCollectionImpl`1.FindSync[TProjection](FilterDefinition`1 filter, FindOptions`2 options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at MongoDB.Driver.FindFluent`2.ToCursor(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at MongoDB.Driver.IAsyncCursorSourceExtensions.Any[TDocument](IAsyncCursorSource`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at MongoDB.Driver.IFindFluentExtensions.Any[TDocument,TProjection](IFindFluent`2 find, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     at CatalogComment.API.Data.CatalogCommentContextSeed.SeedData[T](IMongoCollection`1 productCollection, List`1 seedData) in /src/Services/CatalogComment/CatalogComment.API/Data/CatalogCommentContextSeed.cs:line 9
     at CatalogComment.API.Data.CatalogCommentContext..ctor(IConfiguration configuration) in /src/Services/CatalogComment/CatalogComment.API/Data/CatalogCommentContext.cs:line 16
     at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Span`1& arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
     at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
     at lambda_method9(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<CreateActivator>b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
  --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
     at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
     at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
     at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

and this is my docker-compose.yml

```
    version: '3.4'

services:
  catalogdb:
    image: mongo

  catalogbranddb:
    image: mongo

  catalogcategorydb:
    image: mongo

  catalog.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}catalogapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Services/Catalog/Catalog.API/Dockerfile

  catalogbrand.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}catalogbrandapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Services/CatalogBrand/CatalogBrand.API/Dockerfile


  catalogcategory.api:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}catalogcategoryapi
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Services/CatalogCategory/CatalogCategory.API/Dockerfile
```

and this is my docker-compose-overider.yml

```
    version: '3.4'

services:

  catalogdb:
    container_name: catalogdb
    restart: always
    ports:
        - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
        - ./mongo_data_catalogdb:/data/catalogdb

  catalogcategorydb:
    container_name: catalogcategorydb
    restart: always
    ports:
        - "27018:27017"
    volumes:
        - ./mongo_data_catalogcategorydb:/data/catalogcategorydb

  catalogbranddb:
    container_name: catalogbranddb
    restart: always
    ports:
        - "27019:27017"
    volumes:
        - ./mongo_data_catalogbranddb:/data/catalogbranddb

  catalog.api:
    container_name: catalog.api
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - "DatabaseSettings:ConnectionString=mongodb://catalogdb:27017"
      - "ElasticConfiguration:Uri=http://elasticsearch:9200"
    depends_on:
      - catalogdb
    ports:
      - "8000:80"

  catalogbrand.api:
    container_name: catalogbrand.api
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - "DatabaseSettings:ConnectionString=mongodb://catalogbranddb:27019"
      - "ElasticConfiguration:Uri=http://elasticsearch:9200"
    depends_on:
      - catalogbranddb
    ports:
      - "8001:80"

  catalogcategory.api:
    container_name: catalogcategory.api
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - "DatabaseSettings:ConnectionString=mongodb://catalogcategorydb:27018"
      - "ElasticConfiguration:Uri=http://elasticsearch:9200"
    depends_on:
      - catalogcategorydb
    ports:
      - "8002:80"
```

I'm getting this error in all of the APIs Except Catalog.API
and only catalog.API worked perfectly and I tried to do everything that I did with
Catalog.API but still show error for other services
and these are my container
[image]

somebody tell me how to forward 27017 to 27018 or 27019 without getting this error I'm getting this error in every container that is not 27017

Comment: Connections between containers always use the standard port number; they ignore `ports:` if they're present.  You need to change all of the MongoDB `DatabaseSettings:ConnectionString` client port numbers to the standard port 27017.

Comment: I can connect to ports 27018, 27019, with mongo DB compass and if I run my API from my PC not container, API can access the database with those ports but they can't connect to each other in containers

Comment: Yes, the network environment is different between containers vs. a connection from the host outside a container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this line to your docker-compose under your DB ports

```
command: ["mongod", "--port", "YourFavoritePort"]
```

for example

```
catalogdb:
    container_name: catalogdb
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - mongo_data:/data/db
    ports:
      - "YourFavoritePort:YourFavoritePort"
    command: ["mongod", "--port", "YourFavoritePort"]
```

for example, my favorite port is 27020

```
  catalogdb:
    container_name: catalogdb
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - mongo_data:/data/db
    ports:
      - "27020:27020"
    command: ["mongod", "--port", "27020"]
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with port forwarding. that line you have added will start mongodb at port 27020 INSIDE the container and then you would have to map ports as "27020:27020".

By the way, there was nothing wrong in your compose files, other than its name having an extra "r" character.

Comment: hi @regestea23, I'm facing the same issue but its running on the git-flow test connection fails and throws the same error.

Comment: this error always causes your connection issue, maybe the address of your MongoDB database server is wrong or you have a bad connection so I think it is better to ask a new question with more details so that my friends can help you better

Comment: @regestea23, Sorry I cant open it right now so my question is I'm trying to run dokerfile with test which is built the file and run the test so here my connection failed due to some networks connectivity, how to manage this.

Comment: Also, in addition, for me, the only way I got ASP.NET to read my environment variables was to use two underscores instead of the colon, like so: `"DatabaseSettings__ConnectionString=mongodb://your-super-container-name:YourFavoritePort`

Answer (score 1):

Regarding ports, there are many reasons you are getting error.

1- your app's error log shows you are trying to connect to the wrong port, "27015".

2- your overriding compose file is ending with an extra "r", thus" default "docker compose up" does not read it unless you use "-f" flag

3- if containers use the same docker network, then they will see each other running at port "27017" with their internal docker IPs, not your host forwarded ports "27018/27019". see, they are still not "27015".

PS: the solution you provided above works but you have to remember every single port change you made and edit your files all the time if you change again. that is not feasible. you need to have a "production" and "development" environment files to run your app where you set ports once and they would just work.

Answer (score 1):

you must change
"mongodb://localhost:27017"
to
"mongodb://catalogcategorydb:27017"
in appsettings.json